# For lambda eigenvalue of G , how to prove this statement

Tags: matrices, inequality, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

This is an exercise from a textbook. I have no clue how to start this .

If G is a graph and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalues of G then prove :
$$|\lambda|\le\Delta(G)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an adjacency matrix of $G$ and $|\lambda|>\Delta(G)$ then $A-\lambda I$ is a [strictly diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), so it is non-singular by [Levy–Desplanques theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties), that is $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of  $A$.